# 'os.getcwd()' and './' giving diferent results

Tags: python, path

I'm trying to load a file into python, but it is giving me some unexpected results:

```
os.path.isfile(os.getcwd() + '/data/cars_footprint.csv')
Out[1]: True

os.path.isfile('./data/cars_footprint.csv')
Out[2]: False
```

How is `os.getcwd()` not equal to `./`? I thought `./` was supposed to be synonymous with the current working directory.

Edit: It's returning `True` now for both statements. Still don't understand why it didn't work, and why it does work now.

Comment: Which python version are you using? I tested it out and it worked fine, giving `True` for both of them

Comment: For the second one, maybe try using backslashes

Comment: OS is Windows 11. Python version 3.8.3.

Comment: Are you running from command line or clicking on some short cut?  If command line are you in the directory where the script lives?

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see what path you really use.

Answer (score 1):

Just check your current directory in python. `print(os.getcwd())`
They can be different, in the first case you are using the absolute path, but in the second one - relative.